# Ajax в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Хочу, чтобы метод контроллера вызывался, обновлял модель, но страница при этом не обновлялась. Использую Ajax.
Загрузила unobtrusive-ajax. В web-config добавила

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Во view:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function Click() {
    $.get("/Home/Click");
};
```

Затем

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/java script"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript "></script>
```

Кнопка:

```
<button onclick="Click()">1</button>
```

В контроллере:

```
public void Click(ViewModel model)
{
        model.Count++;
}
```

Click(...) в контроллере даже не вызывается. Что не так?

Comment: параметр в контроллере есть,  а при вызове нет. маршруты какие?

Comment: `$.get("@Url.Content("~/Home/Click")");`